# nix buildPhase fails, "fatal: not a git repository", the .git dir isn't being copied into the build dir?

Tags: nix, nix-flake

I'm trying to create a flake for the peer to peer web browser, agregore ( https://github.com/AgregoreWeb/agregore-browser ). It's my first flake and I'm having major difficulties.

[Here's the full flake](https://gist.github.com/makoConstruct/86153221904431123b005d7d8115cbb1), which I have placed in a clone of the above agregore git repo. I think the relevant section is all just this:

```hs
packages.default = stdenv.mkDerivation {
  pname = "agregore";
  version = (builtins.fromJSON (builtins.readFile ./package.json)).version;
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.git
    pkgs.nodejs
    pkgs.nodePackages.node-gyp
    pkgs.nodePackages.npm
    pkgs.yarn
  ];
  buildPhase = ''
    git submodule update --init --recursive
    yarn
  '';
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/bin
    #TODO find the build output
    ln -s build/agregore $out/bin/agregore
  '';
  src = ./.;
};
```

Logs produced:

```
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "unpackPhase" }
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/va0hnynmqf8h29f580sb6h7d3z9kxcpm-1q603n538l>
source root is 1q603n538laqf3nvkgb5mdr6am8apbda-source
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "patchPhase" }
patching sources
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "configurePhase" }
configuring
no configure script, doing nothing
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "buildPhase" }
building
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I've tried inserting commands like `ls .git/ > out.txt` into the buildPhase, and this produces `ls: cannot access '.git/': No such file or directory`, so they are indeed not being copied over to nix's temporary build directory for this flake (and running the same command with `build/` instead of `.git/` doesn't produce this error.). I can't understand why this would be.

The same command, `git submodule update --init --recursive`, works fine in the original project dir (and I'm running nixos btw), also within a `nix develop` session, so the .git directory really should to be there?

Comment: Yes, that's normal/correct/intended behavior. Nix has options to check out submodules itself; you can't/shouldn't do it after the fact.

Comment: In `fetchgit` and `builtins.fetchGit`, see `fetchSubmodules = true`.

Comment: Remember, Nix builds your code in a sandbox with no network access. You couldn't pull referenced submodules even if you _did_ have a `.git`.

Comment: BTW, if this code is from a flake, use `self` instead of `./.`

Comment: ... https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/4435 is also potentially relevant/interesting/useful background.

Comment: (the other thing is that flakes are pure-by-default; allowing content that isn't hash-addressed -- like the `.git` directory's contents -- would be defeating a big chunk of the point; thus, despite it being a bit of a pain, I'd argue that it's good practice to have everything that might otherwise be pulled as a submodule be listed as a separate flake input).

Comment: Hmm, `self` is never explained in https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Flakes . Is it the flake's directory in the store or something?

Comment: Yes, the flake's directory is added to the store and passed as `self`, with all the same metadata you get from other flake inputs (so you can ask for the git committish and so forth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `mkDerivation` by default cleans `.git` from the source, because it's not appropriate to include it in a reproducible build (`.git` contains things like dangling references to old branches and the like which are completely client-specific). That said, in my opinion `git submodule update --init --recursive` doesn't really belong in the Nix code, because the Nix code assumes that it's operating on a "sane" source structure.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, though it's surprise to me, because I seem to remember hearing somehwere that .git directories are sometimes included in nix packages? (there was explicitly a warning to make sure your .git directory didn't contain any secrets)

Comment: You have to explicitly include it (and it's probably a bad idea in any case); it looks like the relevant parameter is `leaveDotGit`.

Comment: Huh, I'm noticing that .gitmodules is empty, xD I think mauve already replaced the submodules with something else and that build instruction is no longer needed